# Magento import bulk products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import

I am trying to import bulk products in magento  using System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow – Profiles -> Import All Products and after uploading .csv file and clicking on run profile in popup i get a window which is showed in below snapshot. But the products are not getting displayed on magento admin
[image]

But when i am trying to manually insert product using same sku it is giving error as "SKU should be unique " this means that the products are already inserted in database
[image]

Products are not displaying in magento admin as well as on magento website

Comment: I sometimes get problems like this where my import appears to work but then the products don't appear in admin. What I do is make sure all of the required fields are there, so I do an export first (of even just one product) and then use the column headers to create a new template to upload, using the same data as before

Comment: You could also try flushing the cache and reindexing

Comment: i already tried that